# Using R to mutate columns based on the value of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm basically trying to mutate a data set and add a column based on the value of another column in that dataset. How do I do this?

Say I have a data set that looks like this:

```
movies
# A tibble: 651 x 32
                    title   title_type       genre runtime mpaa_rating                   studio
                    <chr>       <fctr>      <fctr>   <dbl>      <fctr>                   <fctr>
 1            Filly Brown Feature Film       Drama      80           R      Indomina Media Inc.
 2               The Dish Feature Film       Drama     101       PG-13    Warner Bros. Pictures
 3    Waiting for Guffman Feature Film      Comedy      84           R   Sony Pictures Classics
 4   The Age of Innocence Feature Film       Drama     139          PG        Columbia Pictures
 ... (more columns and more rows than shown)
```

Say it has a column (not shown) called `thtr_release_month` with possible values equal to a month of the year like "October" or "January"

I want to add a column called `oscar_season` that is either `yes` or `no` if the movie was released in `November` or `December`. How does one do this? I feel like this is close:

```
movies_with_oscar_season <- movies %>% mutate(oscar_season = ifelse(movies$thtr_release_month == 'November' | movies$thtr_release_month == 'December', 'yes', 'no'))
```

What am I missing? How can I improve the above code?

I actually get an error:

`Column oscar_season must be length 651 (the number of rows) or one, not 0 Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> mutate -> mutate.tbl_df`

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a way to write that long `or` expression too?

Comment: Always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: What you want is to add a new column with the value `TRUE` if `thtr_release_month` is `November` or `December`, right?

Comment: instead of TRUE or FALSE, I want 'yes' or 'no'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new vector with the result of evaluating your condition:

```
oscar_season <- (ifelse(movies$thtr_release_month %in% c('November','December')), "yes", "no")
```

***Edit***: *Based on the comments, it is required to show a "yes" or a "no" if the condicion is TRUE or FALSE respectively.*

And then call `mutate` with that new column:

```
movies_oscar_season <- mutate(movies, oscar_season)
```

That should give you the original dataset with the `oscar_season` column.

Comment: Is there another way to write this that is more concise: `(movies$thtr_release_month == 'November') | (movies$thtr_release_month == 'December')`

Comment: Do you mean something like `oscar_season <- (movies$thtr_release_month %in% c("November","December") ) ` ?

Comment: @Jwan622 Take a look at my answer now, I've edit it to a more concise condition and to replace Booleans with "yes" or "no".